# How to switch on another Pane by using selected value from choiceBOX in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX, I am trying to switch on another pane(which is hidden) by using select an option from choice box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use bindings like:

```
firstPane.visibleProperty().bind(choiceBox.valueProperty().isEqualTo(/* Your Condition here */));
secondPane.visibleProperty().bind(choiceBox.valueProperty().isEqualTo(/* Your Condition here */));
```

Comment: How can i bind the choice box using database value